# Show an HTML Link with Custom link

Tags: python, php, html, discord

I have a question
I'm trying to embed a link with HTML data in my own domain so that when I call up my own link, a kind of website opens where the HTML script is shown without me having to download the HTML file
I can imagine that this works with a php file but I don't know what has to be in it

At the moment the link looks like this:

`https://transcript.2icecube.de/https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1024281285839028295/1024281459051200595/transcript-test.html`

whereby the here: `https://transcript.2icecube.de/` is my own domain

and here is the link to the html file: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1024281285839028295/1024281459051200595/transcript-test.html`

However, when I call it, the error 403 always comes up and nothing else

Anyone know how I can create something like this?

Comment: You sound a bit confused: "a kind of website", which you can see without downloading it. My advice is just to visit the discordapp link directly.

Comment: When I just open the discord link it automatically downloads only one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question:

#### First Solution, using `ROUTER`:

it's mean's if someone called `{YOUR_SITE_URL}/attachments/****/****`, it's just handling by your site.

For example (it's written with PHP):

```php
$router = new Router();

$router->all('/attachments/{data}', function ($data) {    
    echo file_get_contents("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/" . $data);
});
```

if you don't want to get from discord, you can Build like this:

```php
$router->all('/embed/{data}', function ($data) {    
    echo file_get_contents($data);
});
```

#### Second Solution, add `CNAME` to your domain

> I'm not exactly sure is this working or not

add `CNAME` to your domain like this:

```
CNAME data.2icecube.de TO cdn.discordapp.com
```

In this case, you just say to your `nameserver` if you get request like this:

```
https://data.2icecube.de/attachments/1024281285839028295/1024281459051200595/transcript-test.html
```

send it to :

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1024281285839028295/1024281459051200595/transcript-test.html
```

I hope it was helpful for you :)

Comment: Can you point out in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/) where we can find the `Router` class?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, ```$router``` is not in the PHP manual! you need to make it yourself, BUT I was using a simple router called [```Bramus\Router```](https://github.com/bramus/router), it's free Composer repo that you can use in your projects